# Ensuring fail-safety of an Apache server

Tags: apache2, configuration, webserver, memory-usage, apache2.4

I have a few Wordpress websites running on Apache 2.4.7 / Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. It is a virtual machine running on Microsoft Azure. The websites are using a MySQL server also running on the same machine. From time to time, the websites become unresponsive and the Apache needs to be restarted. Investigating the error log (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`) reveals the following error:

```
[mpm_prefork:error] [pid 5761] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
```

Here are the contents of the Apache configuration file (`/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf`)

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
        StartServers             5
        MinSpareServers          5
        MaxSpareServers          10
        MaxRequestWorkers        256
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   1000
</IfModule>
```

I have raised the `MaxRequestWorkers` to the maximum number allowed (256), but it still keeps happening. I have tried changing the setting of `MaxConnectionsPerChild`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect either. Sometimes the sites run just fine for weeks, sometimes Apache goes down in a day. Occasionally, MySQL process also stops working and needs to be restarted.

What else should I be checking?

We occasionally do get a bit heavier load of requests to the websites - could this cause the issue? More importantly, though, does this immediately mean we either need to have memory available or the web server will crash? i.e. is there anything to do to ensure fail-safety, no matter how many requests the web server gets?

Comment: Read [this apache doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html), it says you have to increase [serverlimit](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#serverlimit) to increase [maxserverlimit](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers) beyond 256.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have implemented it now, and will keep testing Apache with those settings. Hopefully it will be the solution to the problem we're facing. Nevertheless, the question remains - anything to ensure fail-safety?

Comment: @cccec did you ever find an answer for this, I'm running in to the same issue on Azure.

Comment: my server is crashed after this message appears in the log. I have configured `MaxRequestWorkers        500`

Comment: I'm having same issue in amazon with apache 2.4.. i dont know what else to do. tested everything.. my case have a mod_proxy to a internal port running python apps